# JTextPane - Make Caret Normal Size?

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jtextpane

So I am trying to make the text in a JTextPane double spaced. Here's my code:

```
     MutableAttributeSet attrs = editor.getInputAttributes();
     StyleConstants.setLineSpacing(attrs, 2);
     editor.getStyledDocument().setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength() + 1, attrs, true);
```

The problem with this, is, the curser (caret) is as big as three or four line spaces. How can I resize the caret to normal size?

Here is a screen snip

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
editor.setCaret(new DefaultCaret() {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        JTextComponent comp = getComponent();
        if (comp == null)
            return;

        Rectangle r = null;
        try {
            r = comp.modelToView(getDot());
            if (r == null)
                return;
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            return;
        }
        r.height = 15; //this value changes the caret size
        if (isVisible())
            g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, 1, r.height);
    }
});
```