# Change caret height in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane, caret

How do I alter the caret height in JTextPane, and how do I shift it vertically (make the caret appear to be e.g. 2px lower than normal without moving anything else?

BTW: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809243/jtextpane-make-caret-normal-size) won't work. It makes the caret stop blinking.

Comment: So I take it you didn't get an answer your previous question

Comment: It was missenterpreted. I omitted the part about insets, since it didn't matter, and it seemed to piss people off. And I won't make an SSCCE for this, it's just plain stupid. It's a straightforward question...

Comment: `It's a straightforward question...` Then why are you asking it if the code works? You tried some code and it didn't work, so post the code!!! Its that simple!!! The code from the other posting does not have a frame and a text field so we can't test the code to see what is happening. Of course the problem with this forum is that if you keep posting your question dozens of times, then somebody will answer the question, rather than try to teach somebody how to post a question with all the relevant information

Comment: `How do I alter the caret height in JTextPane, and how do I shift it vertically` - if you can't figure this out with your test program, why do you think we can do this in our head just by looking at the code? I for one like to test my answer so that I don't waste your time. Why should we take the time to create a simple example when you should already have one available. You should be will to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Instead of asking all these questions on the forum why don't you try answer a few and then I'm sure you will understand where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your previous example was that the blink rate wasn't set...

```
JTextPane editor = new JTextPane();
DefaultCaret dc = new DefaultCaret() {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (isVisible()) {

            JTextComponent comp = getComponent();
            if (comp == null) {
                return;
            }

            Rectangle r = null;
            try {
                r = comp.modelToView(getDot());
                if (r == null) {
                    return;
                }
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                return;
            }
            if (isVisible()) {
                g.fillRect(r.x, r.y + 2, 1, r.height - 2);
            }
        }
    }
};
dc.setBlinkRate(500);
editor.setCaret(dc);
```

There is a blink rate property which you should probably use to keep it in sync, but I'll let you figure that out as you need...